# AppleSctipt Finding File with partial filename

Tags: get, applescript, filenames

I am an applescript noob and i need help getting a certain log file that has a long string of numbers in its title. The number changes and the filename before the number string is unique to the folder it is in. Is there some way i can use the "starts with" to retrieve the file with only using part of the filename and make a variable to work with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is best done with shell script. Use "do shell script" if you must do it in AppleScript. You can concatenate the string part of do shell script with whatever you want, for example:

```
set file_start to "file_start"
set file_ext to ".txt"
do shell script "mdfind -name " & quoted form of file_start & "|grep " & quoted form of (file_start & "[0-9]*" & file_ext & "$")
```

replace file_start in quotations with your file's non-changing beginning, and replace the extension with whatever you're using.

Answer (score 0):

`do shell command "find ~/some/directory -iname *somefile*"`
This actually ended up working a little better.